# Automatically run scripts in R. NOT BASH

Tags: sql, automation, rstudio, rstudio-server

Does any one know the way to run my script (it takes data from SQL and excel files) automatically everyday? 
I know it can do bash file and task scheduler but I’m looking for something else.

Comment: Have you looked at SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system, you should take a look at one of these R packages, which will do the work for you:

Windows - https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR

Unix/Linux - https://github.com/bnosac/cronR